# crear modificar volume javescript

Tags: javascript, html, css

Hola necesito modificar el volume del reproductor web pero no va como yo quiero, quiero que el relleno empieze desde el minimo y cuando muevo el circulo del volume que rellene de izquerda a derecha como debe ir adjunto codigo.

```js
const playCircle = document.getElementById('playCircle');
const volumePath = document.querySelector('.volume-path');
const volumeFill = document.querySelector('.volume-fill');
const volumeKnob = document.querySelector('.volume-knob');
const audioPlayer = document.getElementById('audioPlayer');
let isPlaying = false;
let isDragging = false;
playCircle.addEventListener('click', () => {
  if (isPlaying) {
    audioPlayer.pause();
  } else {
    audioPlayer.play();
  }
  isPlaying = !isPlaying;
  updatePlayCircle();
});
function updatePlayCircle() {
  if (isPlaying) {
    playCircle.classList.add('active');
  } else {
    playCircle.classList.remove('active');
  }
}
function getPointOnPath(path, percentage) {
  const pathLength = path.getTotalLength();
  const point = path.getPointAtLength(percentage * pathLength);
  return point;
}
function updateVolume(x) {
  const volumePath = document.querySelector('.volume-path');
  const svg = document.querySelector('.volume-svg');
  const svgRect = svg.getBoundingClientRect();
  const svgWidth = svgRect.width;
  const svgLeft = svgRect.left;
  let volumePercentage = (x - svgLeft) / svgWidth;
  volumePercentage = Math.min(Math.max(volumePercentage, 0), 1);
  audioPlayer.volume = volumePercentage;
  const knobX = volumePercentage * 200; // Posición del círculo en la barra (200 es el ancho de la barra)
  const point = getPointOnPath(volumePath, knobX / 220); // Normalizamos la posición del círculo a la longitud total del path
  // Ajuste para que el relleno vaya desde M 10,55 hacia la derecha hasta la posición del círculo
  const arcFlag = volumePercentage > 0.5 ? 1 : 0; // 1 para sentido de las agujas del reloj, 0 para sentido contrario
  volumeFill.setAttribute('d', `M 10,55 A 45,45 0 ${arcFlag},1 ${point.x},${point.y}`);
  volumeFill.setAttribute('stroke-dashoffset', 275 - volumePercentage * 275);
  volumeKnob.setAttribute('cx', point.x);
  volumeKnob.setAttribute('cy', point.y);
}
volumeKnob.addEventListener('mousedown', (e) => {
  isDragging = true;
  updateVolume(e.clientX);
});
document.addEventListener('mousemove', (e) => {
  if (isDragging) {
    updateVolume(e.clientX);
  }
});
document.addEventListener('mouseup', () => {
  isDragging = false;
});
// Actualización inicial del círculo de manipulación en la posición de 0
updateVolume(10); // Establecemos la posición inicial del círculo al inicio de la barra
updatePlayCircle();
```

```css
body {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  height: 100vh;
  background-color: #f0f0f0;
  margin: 0;
}
.player-container {
  position: relative;
  width: 220px;
  height: 220px;
}
.circle {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background-color: #ccc;
  cursor: pointer;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  transition: background-color 0.2s ease;
  z-index: 3; /* Mover el círculo hacia adelante */
}
.circle.active {
  background-color: #ff5733;
}
.volume-container {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: -100px;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translateX(-50%);
  width: 220px;
  height: 300px;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.volume-svg {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
.volume-path {
  fill: none;
  stroke: #ccc;
  stroke-width: 10;
  stroke-linecap: round;
  transition: stroke 0.2s ease;
  z-index: 2;
}
.volume-fill {
  fill: none;
  stroke: #ff5733;
  stroke-width: 10;
  stroke-linecap: round;
  stroke-dasharray: 275; /* Longitud total de la barra (220 + 45 + 10) */
  stroke-dashoffset: 275; /* Valor inicial para que el relleno esté vacío */
  z-index: 1; /* Mover el relleno detrás del círculo */
}
.volume-knob {
  fill: #ff5733;
  cursor: pointer;
  z-index: 4; /* Mover el círculo del volumen más adelante */
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>Reproductor con Control de Volumen</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
</head>
<body>
  <div class="player-container">
    <div class="circle" id="playCircle"></div>
    <audio id="audioPlayer">
      <source src="https://play.los40.com/widget/directo/los40_dance/" type="audio/mpeg">
      Tu navegador no admite el elemento de audio.
    </audio>
    <div class="volume-container">
      <svg class="volume-svg" viewBox="0 0 220 110" width="220" height="110">
        <path class="volume-path" d="M 10,55 A 45,45 0 0,0 210,55"></path>
        <path class="volume-fill"></path>
        <circle class="volume-knob" cx="10" cy="55" r="10"></circle>
      </svg>
    </div>
  </div>
  <script src="script.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yo usuaria `stroke-dasharray`, que genera una línea divida por espacios

Su sintaxis es la siguiente:
`stroke-dasharray="<dash-length>, <gap-length>"`

```
              gap-length     dash-length
               _______          _____
               |     |          |   |
               V     V          V   V           
----      -----      -----      -----
```

Donde:

- gap-length: Es el espacio entre líneas
- dash-length: Es el largo de la línea

Entonces si hacemos que el `gap-length` mida "medio arco" solo mostrará una línea (porque la siguiente queda fuera el área de visión)

Y Digamos que "medio arco" vale `315` y que el porcentaje del volumen está entre 0 y 1

tendríamos que:

- 10%: stroke-dasharray = "0.1*315, 315";
- 20%: stroke-dasharray = "0.2*315, 315";
- 30%: stroke-dasharray = "0.3*315, 315";
- Etc..

*nota: Además hay que eliminar el atributo `stroke-dashoffset`; y los `stroke-dasharray: 275;` `stroke-dashoffset: 275;*` del css para que no interfieran*

Demo

```js
const playCircle = document.getElementById('playCircle');
const volumePath = document.querySelector('.volume-path');
const volumeFill = document.querySelector('.volume-fill');
const volumeKnob = document.querySelector('.volume-knob');
const audioPlayer = document.getElementById('audioPlayer');
let isPlaying = false;
let isDragging = false;
playCircle.addEventListener('click', () => {
  if (isPlaying) {
    audioPlayer.pause();
  } else {
    audioPlayer.play();
  }
  isPlaying = !isPlaying;
  updatePlayCircle();
});
function updatePlayCircle() {
  if (isPlaying) {
    playCircle.classList.add('active');
  } else {
    playCircle.classList.remove('active');
  }
}
function getPointOnPath(path, percentage) {
  const pathLength = path.getTotalLength();
  const point = path.getPointAtLength(percentage * pathLength);
  return point;
}
function updateVolume(x) {
  const volumePath = document.querySelector('.volume-path');
  const svg = document.querySelector('.volume-svg');
  const svgRect = svg.getBoundingClientRect();
  const svgWidth = svgRect.width;
  const svgLeft = svgRect.left;
  let volumePercentage = (x - svgLeft) / svgWidth;
  volumePercentage = Math.min(Math.max(volumePercentage, 0), 1);
  audioPlayer.volume = volumePercentage;
  const knobX = volumePercentage * 200; // Posición del círculo en la barra (200 es el ancho de la barra)
  const point = getPointOnPath(volumePath, knobX / 220); // Normalizamos la posición del círculo a la longitud total del path
  // Ajuste para que el relleno vaya desde M 10,55 hacia la derecha hasta la posición del círculo
  const arcFlag = volumePercentage > 0.5 ? 1 : 0; // 1 para sentido de las agujas del reloj, 0 para sentido contrario
  
  
  //ESTO ES LO NUEVO ===========================
  const media_arc=315;
  volumeFill.setAttribute('stroke-dasharray', `${volumePercentage * media_arc}, ${media_arc}`);
  //=============================================
  
  
  volumeKnob.setAttribute('cx', point.x);
  volumeKnob.setAttribute('cy', point.y);
}
volumeKnob.addEventListener('mousedown', (e) => {
  isDragging = true;
  updateVolume(e.clientX);
});
document.addEventListener('mousemove', (e) => {
  if (isDragging) {
    updateVolume(e.clientX);
  }
});
document.addEventListener('mouseup', () => {
  isDragging = false;
});
// Actualización inicial del círculo de manipulación en la posición de 0
updateVolume(10); // Establecemos la posición inicial del círculo al inicio de la barra
updatePlayCircle();
```

```css
body {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  height: 100vh;
  background-color: #f0f0f0;
  margin: 0;
}
.player-container {
  position: relative;
  width: 220px;
  height: 220px;
}
.circle {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background-color: #ccc;
  cursor: pointer;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  transition: background-color 0.2s ease;
  z-index: 3; /* Mover el círculo hacia adelante */
}
.circle.active {
  background-color: #ff5733;
}
.volume-container {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: -100px;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translateX(-50%);
  width: 220px;
  height: 300px;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.volume-svg {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
.volume-path {
  fill: none;
  stroke: #ccc;
  stroke-width: 10;
  stroke-linecap: round;
  transition: stroke 0.2s ease;
  z-index: 2;
}
.volume-fill {
  fill: none;
  stroke: #ff5733;
  stroke-width: 10;
  stroke-linecap: round;

  z-index: 1; /* Mover el relleno detrás del círculo */
}
.volume-knob {
  fill: #ff5733;
  cursor: pointer;
  z-index: 4; /* Mover el círculo del volumen más adelante */
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>Reproductor con Control de Volumen</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
</head>
<body>
  <div class="player-container">
    <div class="circle" id="playCircle"></div>
    <audio id="audioPlayer">
      <source src="https://play.los40.com/widget/directo/los40_dance/" type="audio/mpeg">
      Tu navegador no admite el elemento de audio.
    </audio>
    <div class="volume-container">
      <svg class="volume-svg" viewBox="0 0 220 110" width="220" height="110">
        <path class="volume-path" d="M 10,55 A 45,45 0 0,0 210,55"></path>
        <path class="volume-fill" d="M 10,55 A 45,45 0 0,0 210,55" stroke-dasharray="0, 315"></path>
        <circle class="volume-knob" cx="10" cy="55" r="10"></circle>
      </svg>
    </div>
  </div>
  <script src="script.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

**Tu código tiene otro problema, el cual la bola no sigue correctamente los porcentajes del volumen. Pero eso escapa a la pregunta que realizaste.**

Comment: vale gracias, por la explicacion, pero veo que al pasar del medio me cre el relleno por encima del circulo a la derecha

Comment: @DanielOvidiu No es crezca el circulo a la derecha, es que la bola no sigue correctamente el porcentaje (es lo que te puse en último párrafo). Si te fifas la bola no llega al final